# WebAPI Issue: for passing customer object from client to action

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

i am trying to perform crud operation by web api. so i pass customer json from client to web api action.

this is my json which i passed from client to action.

```
{"CustomerID":"James","CompanyName":"jame pvt","ContactName":"James","ContactTitle":"Sr Developer","Address":"Salt lake","Region":"sect-1","PostalCode":"700009","City":"kolinara","Country":"India","Phone":"033-8547-4789","Fax":"033-8547-4781"}
```

### my web api action looks as below

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
    [HttpPost, Route("AddCustomer")]
            public HttpResponseMessage PostCustomer(Customer customer)
            {
                customer = repository.Add(customer);
                var response = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);
                response.ReasonPhrase = "Customer successfully added";
                string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = customer.CustomerID });
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
                return response;
            }
}
```

### this way i try to call action from httpclient from winform apps

```
private async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer oCustomer = new Customer
            {
                CustomerID = "James",
                CompanyName = "James pvt",
                ContactName = "James",
                ContactTitle = "Sr Developer",
                Address = "Salt lake",
                Region = "sect-1",
                PostalCode = "700009",
                City = "Kolinara",
                Country = "India",
                Phone = "033-8547-4789",
                Fax = "033-8547-4781"
            };

            var fullAddress = "http://localhost:38762/api/customer/AddCustomer";

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var serializedCustomer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oCustomer);
                    var content = new StringContent(serializedCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    using (var response = client.PostAsync(fullAddress, content).Result)
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var customerJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            //_Customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Customer>>(customerJsonString);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                            var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                            MessageBox.Show(dict["Message"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // catch any exception here
            }
        }
```

this is the error message i got when i do the same from fiddler.
the error msg is :

> {"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type
>   header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not
>   supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Customer'
>   from content with media type
>   'application/octet-stream'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content,
>   Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

now please tell me what is wrong in my code for which i am getting error.

thanks

Comment: please use "[FromBody]Customer customer" as input paramter

Answer (score 2):

Naturally this error beacuse of not setting Content-Type to: application/json.
I have implemented my code by this way.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:38762/api/customer/AddCustome");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
  .Accept
  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"relativeAddress");
 var serializedCustomer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oCustomer);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  request.Content = content;
  client.SendAsync(request)
  .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
  });
```

Comment: I just add the following in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs class in Web API project.

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")` then why we need to again set application/json for calling action with post and customer json?

Comment: config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new
System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")); by setting this you are telling to return json type. You don't tell web api that your request type is application/json 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110659/Formatters-and-Content-Negotiation-in-ASP-NET-Web

Comment: i set the content type...see my above code `var content = new StringContent(serializedCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` then why we need to add again the same with your link `DefaultRequestHeaders` ?